# Screen is not turning off in the application when user is doing nothing

Tags: android, screen, power-management

I have developed the game. On the main game screen, when user doing nothing, phone is not turning off. What could be wrong in my implementation?

I can provide code, but I don't know what could help to identify this problem.

Comment: Have you checked if there is any [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) in your [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html)?

Comment: maybe you set android:KeepScreenOn="true".

Comment: Yep, exactly KeepScreenOn. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Verify at your manifest if you activity have the WAKE_LOCK permission set ;)

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't help. Actually some activities which are responsible for main menu are turning off, but the main game screen , which has view thread, is always ON.

Comment: Well, the activity should not have this permission set. This way the screen will never shut off